# Action view intent cannot open image in files dir with fileProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, png, actionview

What it is, is that I have an image in the files directory of my app. And then I want to open it with an intent, action view.

I have been on this for ages it seems and it just does not want to work out for me.

I have the following code:

```
private void changeInputFileViewer(File file){
    boolean noApp = false;

    file = new File(getFilesDir()+"/test.png");

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.mayzom", file), "image/png");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        noApp = true;
    }
    if (noApp){
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.noApp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:authorities="com.example.mayzom"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Provider paths:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
</paths>`

The image exists with the following path found in the device file explorer: ***/data/data/com.example.mayzom/files/test.png***.

[image]

The image is opened as this an endless buffer, with the following info: [image]

I looked around online for a fix for a former error and thus, I have the following code in my onCreate: `StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());`

Comment: Other apps have no access to your apps private directory getFilesDir(). But apart from that: Dont use Uri.fromFile() but use FileProvider to serve your file and construct an uri.

Comment: So where should I store my files? Android seems to be very strict with this (for good reasons, of course).

Comment: You can leave them where they are. I did not say that you should store them differently. Please reread.

Comment: Oh okay, so I store them correctly. But the FileProvider needs to make a correct Uri for it to work?

Comment: You rereaded well.

Comment: I have now added a file provider. The image is just left buffering. The path for the image is: content://com.example.mayzom/files/test.png

Comment: It is unclear to me what you wanna say and if all works now. That is not a path but a content scheme.

Comment: Sorry. I'll elaborate. It does not work. The action view attempts to open a file with the following path: content://com.example.mayzom/files/test.png or in another iteration content://com.example.mayzom.provider/files/test.png. Neither of these work. The image is just "buffering", not shown, not working. So what am I doing wrong. How do I turn it from a content scheme to a path?

Comment: The used intent is not ok. You should set EXTRA_OUTPUT or something like that with your new uri. Google for examples.

Comment: One does not turn a content scheme to a path. And moreover you know the path as you converted it to a content scheme. And now you wanna convert it back? That is not possible. And moreover.. you know the path already..

Comment: Then can you lead me in the correct direction? How do I approach opening a file in my files directory in an action view intent?

Comment: I already told you all. Use EXTRA_OUTPUT at your intent. For the rest your code is fine.

Comment: Aha.. you should also set a flag at your intent. Intent.GRAND_READ_URI_PERMISSION or something like that.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. But without the extra_output though. Do you want to provide an answer, so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to add a more fulfilling answer than what it is in the comments.

You need to create a fileProvider. You can find a guide [here](https://medium.com/@ali.dev/open-a-file-in-another-app-with-android-fileprovider-for-android-7-42c9abb198c1), afterwards you need the following code for your intent

```
boolean noApp = false;

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName()+".provider", file), "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        noApp = true;
    }
    if (noApp){
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.noApp), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```